# Possible memory leak with chrome extension content script after closing properly

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a memory issue with an extension. Here's the scenario. On each tab with `CMD+SHIFT+K`, you can open a view.  This view is an iFrame injected via a content script.

After being idle for 15 seconds the iFrame is removed.
When the extension first starts `Javascript Memory` is around **6MB**.
But after it's been removed `Javascript Memory` hovers around **14MB**

This looks like a memory leak, but what's odd is when I remove the iFrame it's with this snippet of code.

```
const cleanIFrame = () => {
    let frames = document.querySelectorAll('#iframe-id');

    for (let i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
        let frameElement = frames[i];
        if (frameElement.parentNode) {
            frameElement.parentNode.removeChild(frameElement);
            frameElement = null;
        }
    }
    frames = null;
};
```

Here are screenshots of what I'm seeing in Task Manager

**Only opening one iFrame to check if there's a memory leak**
[image]

**Real scenario: Opening multiple iFrames in different tabs (5-10)**
`Javascript Memory` is around **120MB**
[image]

Is Chrome unable to remove the iFrames from memory with `GC`?

---

Update 1: Mon June 03, 2019

**Memory Profiler** with JS VM Intance
[image]

Update 2:

[image]
This is a screenshot of:

- top: background extension memory tab
- bottom: content script iFrame memory tab
- middle: task manager

What would indicate a high **Memory Footprint** of 214MB when the Javascript VM instance for both background and content_script iframe is low?

Update 3:

[image]
Looking at `Heap snapshot`, I'm seeing `Detached HTMLDivElements` increase. This requires the user to interact with the iFrame.
This is a `React` app, curious if this is a React problem or Chrome not removing the elements.
Notice the last snapshot. I pressed **Collect Garbage**, but no change

Comment: If your other code accesses the iframe contents directly it may hold references that prevent GC.

Comment: Thanks wOxxOm, I figured that could be the problem but unsure where. I'm currently analyzing my code and a library which could potentially keep a reference to an iFrame. For example, I use `iframe-resizer`: https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer

What I've noticed in Chrome Canary is that the `JavaScript VM instance` shows the iFrame for the duration of its existence.
Once the 15 seconds are up, the VM instance is removed. Is that a sign that the GC is properly removing the resources? (I've posted a screenshot of the VM when the iFrame is injected)

Comment: I've posted another screenshot comparing **JS VM instance** vs **Task Manager**
What would indicate a high **Memory Footprint** of 214MB when the Javascript VM instance for both background and content_script iframe are low?

Comment: Does the problem go away in a couple of minutes if devtools is not open? As for the culprit, it could be a messaging port that wasn't closed, for example due to incorrect use of "return true" in the onMessage listener. You can also try a much older portable Chrome - maybe this is a recent bug in the browser.

Comment: Does the problem go away in a couple of minutes if devtools is not open? 
No, in the wild it's been reported by users that the app reaches 1GB-2GB of memory footprint. I don't think devtools closed would help.

As for the messaging port, I'm unsure how incorrect use of "return true" would cause an issue. 
If I understand correctly, only use `return true` if the side sending the message uses a callback.

Comment: In general, if I don't use `sendResponse` function I simply `return` or let the function call finish.
To be specific, I'm looking at this particular API: `chrome.runtime.onMessage`

Comment: I added a Heap Snapshot of the problem. I'm noticing an increase in `Detached HTMLElements` That looks to me like that could impact **Memory Footprint** in Task Manager.
Although not sure if this is a React problem? When would Chrome resolve these detached elements?  **GC** is not clearing them.